# Typescript extend method declaration without reimplementation

Tags: typescript, oop, types

I have a class which is to be extended by various sub classes. Each sub class doesn't need to reimplement the class methods, but only the declaration to infer proper type check.

As an example:

```
class QueryBuilder {
    insert<T>(data: T): string {
        return '';
    }   
}

class User extends QueryBuilder {
    insert<IUser>(data: IUser): string;
}

interface IUser {
    name: string,
    email: string
}
```

This way i get the following error:

```
Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.
(method) User.insert<IUser>(data: IUser): string
```

Is there a way to get what i want without having to repeat the implementation for every sub class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two main ways to go about this. The first is to move the generic parameter to the class. You can even give it a default value if you want to use it in a collection or something:

```
class QueryBuilder<T = any> {
    insert(data: T): string {
        return "";
    }
}

class User extends QueryBuilder<IUser> { }
```

There's another trick you can do if the type you want is available on the base class as a property:

```
class QueryBuilder {
    data: {};
    insert(data: this["data"]): string {
        return "";
    }
}

class User extends QueryBuilder {
    data: IUser;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Instead of assigning the generic type to each method, i should have assigned it to the the class, like this:

```
class QueryBuilder<T> {
    insert(data: T): string {
        return '';
    }   
}

// Just set your interface as the generic type when extending,
// typechecking will work correctly now
class User extends QueryBuilder<IUser> {     
}

interface IUser {
    name: string,
    email: string
}

const user = new User();

user.insert('foo') // error
user.insert({ username: '' }) // error
user.insert({ name: '', email: '' }) // correct
```